# Ckeditor 4+ Inline editing with iFrame: Code is not being written properly

Tags: iframe, ckeditor, inline, wysiwyg, editing

i'm using Ckeditor 4+ for inline Editing. When changes are applied to a div with the contenteditable attribute they are written into a database.

When I want to display the contents (now without the inline editor), iFrames are not displayed properly.

Instead of showing an iFrame tag, an img tag is being 
produced.
In my understanding, the img tag is being used while inline editing to not show the content of the iFrame.

When i put the following iFrame into the database,

```
<iframe src="//www.youtube.com/embed/VIDEOLINK" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
```

and then display it within the inline editor, it shows the img tag.
When I edit the content and save it to the database, the following code is being produced:

```
<img 
 class="cke_iframe" 
 data-cke-realelement="%3Ciframe%20src%3D%22%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fembed%2FVIDEOLINK%22%20frameborder%3D%220%22%20allowfullscreen%3D%22%22%3E%3C%2Fiframe%3E"
 data-cke-real-node-type="1" 
 alt="IFrame" 
 title="IFrame" 
 align=""
 src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAPABAP///wAAACH5BAEKAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" 
 data-cke-real-element-type="iframe" 
 data-cke-resizable="true">
```

instead of an iFrame tag.

I added in the config.js file the following line:

```
config.allowedContent = true;
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

> What am I doing wrong?

You're trying to get HTML directly from the editable element, instead of getting data from the editor. These are two completely different things. What's inside CKEditor is not what you're interested in unless you're writing a plugin for CKEditor of course. You want to get data using [`editor.getData()`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-method-getData) and that's all.

Answer (score 0):

> in config.js

```
   CKEDITOR.plugins.registered['save']={
        init : function( editor ){
            var command = editor.addCommand( 'save', {
                modes : { wysiwyg:1, source:1 },
                exec : function( editor, bla ) {
                    //saveEditor(editor.document.getBody().getHtml());
                    saveEditor(editor.getData());
                }
            });
        editor.ui.addButton( 'Save',{label : '',command : 'save'});
        }
    };
```